# SoundManager + FFMPEG causing loud popping sound when streaming MP3s?

Tags: streaming, audio, mp3, ffmpeg

I built an application that plays both uploaded original mp3 files, and copies that have been converted with FFMPEG. I am finding that in *some* cases the FFMPEG files have a horrible popping/clicking/screeching sound for a split second at startup (hear below). But when I analyze the file in an audio editor there is nothing there, so it seems to be either the browser or soundManager reacting badly to something in that file. Wondering if there is any way I can fix this either by adjusting FFMPEG settings, soundManager settings, or..... Any suggestions?

I've uploaded the offending sound in the link below (before the music starts playing).

[Hear sound](http://www.divshare.com/download/8291946-af9)

Answer (score 1):

Screeching/clicking at the beginning often points to a badly formed mp3 file.  (There are a lot of them in the wild.)

Try checking both the original and converted files with [`mp3check`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3check/) `-e -B`

If you get errors, adding `mp3check --cut-junk-start` to your pipline should work.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I ran one of the source MP3s in mp3 check, and there was indeed a bad frame, with a “possible id3v2 tag” problem. Do you know if there is a way to auto-correct these files with FFMPEG? The problem is that users will be uploading their own MP3 files, and many don't know that there are issues with their tags, as the tracks play perfect fine in music players like iTunes. It would be ideal if there was something that we could do on our end to automatically fix the tags, or use some other workaround, so the tracks stream without this popping sound.